# Objective-C/CocoaHTTPServer - Is it possible to return response to the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoahttpserver

I am developing an iPhone app which is using CocoaHTTPServer for making remote server communication.

The app will send the request details to the CocoaHTTPServer which will store the request locally. Once the internet connectivity is available, CocoaHTTPServer will send the request to remote server & will get the server response now CocoaHTTPServer has to send this response back to the app,

But I am confused how to implement it. Is there any inter app communication api for the same?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RDC , this will go to Ram ,Who can Guide you

Comment: If an app declares itself as handler for a unique type of URL and you know the format you can open the URL with its parameters.

Comment: @uchuugaka but is it possible for a background app to open a URL and that ultimately invokes another app?

Comment: Best way is to try it, but if I recall correctly, it should be a user initiated event to switch apps...

Comment: iOS 8 might offer new things for you, not sure.

Comment: Your CocoaHTTPService is running in the same process as the app, so you should not need any kind of IPC. However it seems like you are trying to implement HTTP caching, which iOS already provides. The CocoaHTTPServer layer you have is likely unnecessary.

Comment: @quellish I want to make a CocoaHTTPServer as a separate app so that multiple apps in the device can communicate with it for the remote server connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL scheme can be used to send the response back to the app. The response from the remote server can be set as a parameter in the URL. The CocoaHTTPServer can invoke the other app which will be the handler of this unique URL. The below link provides more information on the same.

[Inter-AppCommunication using URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well , I haven't workaround CocoaHTTP server classes so can't explain you verywell but I found there are couple of tutorials will surly guide you.

**Thanks to  [Matt Gallagher](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html) for such a detailed article.**

You can listen for a connection using NSFileHandle class

```
listeningHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc]
    initWithFileDescriptor:fileDescriptor
    closeOnDealloc:YES];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receiveIncomingConnectionNotification:)
    name:NSFileHandleConnectionAcceptedNotification
    object:nil];
[listeningHandle acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify];
```

When receiveIncomingConnectionNotification: is invoked, each new incoming connection will get its own NSFileHandle. If you're keeping track, you can handle received message

```
if(CFHTTPMessageIsHeaderComplete(incomingRequest))
{
    HTTPResponseHandler *handler =
        [HTTPResponseHandler
            handlerForRequest:incomingRequest
            fileHandle:incomingFileHandle
            server:self];

    [responseHandlers addObject:handler];
    [self stopReceivingForFileHandle:incomingFileHandle close:NO];

    [handler startResponse];
    return;
}
```

Note : please go through the full article, it has nice explanation.

Apart from this you may have look on [this](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/tree/master/Samples/iPhoneHTTPServer) as well.

Hope this will give you some idea.

Answer (score 1):

You question is focussing on background proces.

When an App goes into background, it get very limited time to finish things up. After that the App freezes in background. That is not a good situation to start communication.

Apple states clearly that the priority is always on the running foreground tasks.

The Notification mechanism (as listed by RDC above) is created to handle external events. During such a wake up you can send/receive a little bit of data, however you'll get minimal priority. Since timing is important in communication, I would not go for that either.

I suggest checking communication during the wakeup call and start activities then. And use the Notification mechanism to wakeup the user, that network is up again.